# Is $(log_2x)^{log_2(x)}$ an exponential function?

Tags: asymptotics, exponential-function

From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function), an exponential function is a function like this:

> $b^x$

but I cannot figure that this function is an exponential function even after I convert it to this form:

> $\log_2\big((\log_2x)^{\log_2(x)}\big)=\log_2n(\log_2\log_2n)$

Comment: Please fix your markup. What you wrote is unreadable.

Comment: @anomaly can you help me fix this? I don't know why it's showing this way.

Comment: MathJax hint:  putting a backslash before common functions gets the proper font and spacing, so \log x gives $\log x$.  For multicharacter exponents, put them in braces, so x^{11} gives $x^{11}$ in contrast to x^11 which gives $x^11$  Everything in braces gets treated as a unit.  It also works for subscripts, fractions, etc.  You can right click on any MathJax, pick Show Math As ->TeX Commands and see how it is done.  That is how I learned a lot.

Comment: Who said it was an exponential function ? (Also note that the Edit #3 was good. Maybe you should rollback.)

Comment: @Zubzub I saw it at a problem of ordering functions solution, It classified this into exponential order functions.

Comment: $\log(x)^{\log(x)}$ grows faster than any polynomial but slower than any exponential (with base $> 1$).

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret so how can I prove it?

Comment: $\log(x^n) = n\log(x)$, $\log(\log(x)^{\log(x)}) = \log(\log(x))\log(x)$, $\log(a^x) = x\log(a)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't. It has quasi-polynomial growth, not exponential. Quasi-polynomial is $2^{O((\log_2n)^c)}$ for some $c>0$; if $c>1$ this is faster growing than polynomial, but slower-growing than exponential. Here you have $(\log_2 n)^{\log_2 n}=2^{(\log_2 n)(\log_2\log_2 n)}=2^{O((\log_2 n)^2)}$ (in fact, any $c>1$ would work).

Exponential functions grow like $2^{\Omega(n)}$. Since $(\log_2 n)^c=o(n)$ for any $c>0$, quasi-polynomial functions are not exponential.

Comment: No need to introduce all this terminology and notation. It's trivial that $\log^{\log}$ grows faster than polynomials and slower than exponentials